# Save captured video to Library in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I know it's possible to save images to the Library using `navigator.camera.getPicture` with the `saveToPhotoAlbum` setting, but for video you are limited to the `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` function which does not support that or a similar option.

Is it possible to save a recorded video to the Library on Android and/or iOS? Maybe manually download the file in the capture video function callback to the Library?

I'm using the latest version (2.8.0) of PhoneGap.